# I am new in laravel, trying to store data into multiple tables through api from one controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There will be four tables, in which first table id is the primary key and for other tables it will be foreign key.How to insert data.
data should be related to the first table id only.

Comment: show the code you have tried.

Comment: Did you create any Eloquent models? Please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: You are looking for the https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models (it's down a bit in that section).

Comment: you can using Relationships in laravel

Comment: actually i am new to this can you please share an example regarding this

Comment: Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

you can manage it by retrieve the id(Primary Key) of the stored ligne. Just like that

```
$primId = PrimModel::create([$datas]);
/* where datas are the informations you want to store
eg : $primId = PrimModel::create(['arg1' => 'val1', 'arg2'=> $val2, ...]); */
//Now you can store the others like that
ForeignModel::create(['primId' => $primId->id, ...]);
...
```

Hope this could help you.